# PowerBI Desktop Cant Connect to Multidimensional Cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi

[image: Cont Connect]
I am trying to connect to Multidimensional Cube but it shows me error as above.
The SQL Server version is 2016 so thats not an issue. The SQL Browser service is running on the SQL Server host machine.
I can connect to the cubes using Excel so no question of firewall as well.
I will be glad if any one can help me with what could be the cause of this happening?
Also, i can connect to the Tabular Cube with the same PowerBI desktop just not the multidimensional one.

Comment: Are SSASTAB and SSASMD on the same server?  Or different servers?

Comment: they are on different servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I explicitly add the name of the database it works.

Comment: Same process worked for me.  Although I am not comfortable with this.  I have two MD servers, and one of the connections works without the explicit database name.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have successfully connected PBI to Multidimensional cubes with no issue.  To reassure myself of this functionality, I launched PBI Desktop to test this out.  To my surprise, I ran into the same issue.  I wanted to also share my experience.

**Connections:**

I tried to connect `PBI Desktop to my SSAS instance on Server 'GCOD039'`, a *DEV Server*.  To my surprise, I received an error message (the same error message as OP).  Shocked, I then tried connecting `PBI Desktop to SSAS on Server 'GCOP039'`, the *PROD Server*.  The 'GCOP039' connection was made successfully.  I then tried `Excel connection to 'GCOD039'`... that works just fine.  So, why does PBI not connect?

I presented this scenario to my colleague (the SSAS Admin), he tested the connection on his PC to 'GCDO039' and it worked for him.  He suggested I reboot my PC.  I did, and my connection to 'GCOD039' is still unsuccessful.  Currently we are both stumped.

I am working to seek an answer for what could cause this...

**PBIDesktop-SSASMD-connection-issue.png**
[image]